# How to make HTML embed code from YouTube W3C compliant?

Tags: html, youtube, embed, w3c, w3c-validation

Here is an example of the embed code from a Youtube Video:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <title>I AM YOUR DOCUMENT TITLE REPLACE ME</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
</head>
<body>
   <div>

<object width="1280" height="750">
    <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/WZ-1lfammjk?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/WZ-1lfammjk?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="1280" height="750"></embed>
</object>

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I made this go through the W3C HTML 4.01 Strict validator, and got the following errors:

```
Line 13, Column 115: end tag for element "PARAM" which is not open

Line 14, Column 55: end tag for element "PARAM" which is not open

Line 15, Column 59: end tag for element "PARAM" which is not open

Line 16, Column 16: there is no attribute "SRC"

Line 16, Column 98: there is no attribute "TYPE"

Line 16, Column 148: there is no attribute "ALLOWSCRIPTACCESS"

Line 16, Column 173: there is no attribute "ALLOWFULLSCREEN"

Line 16, Column 186: there is no attribute "WIDTH"

Line 16, Column 200: there is no attribute "HEIGHT"

Line 16, Column 205: element "EMBED" undefined
```

What can I do to fix this? I have limited experience, so detailed answers would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You heard. Did you check? What did the validator complain about?

Comment: Most of us stopped validating a while ago due to spotty support of HTML5 and CSS3, as long as your code works in every browser you support then who cares?

Comment: What doctype? http://validator.w3.org can tell you whether it is...

Comment: Just checked, I edited the question to include the errors from W3C, which validated my HTML fragment to HTML 4.01 strict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what version you're validating for.
To check your code, use the [W3CValidation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)

Here is a [direct link](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options) to validate just a portion of code.

**EDIT**

Try using this embed code instead:

`<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width:425px; height:350px;" data="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/WZ-1lfammjk?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"><param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/WZ-1lfammjk?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" /></object>`

This embed code validated on HTML 4.01 Strict and HTML5 just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use this W3C [validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options). Make sure you validate it as an HTML fragment, not a whole document.